# Postgresql: How to insert or update a record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update the data, and if they are not in the database, then insert and return the key. Unfortunately, I can't use merge, on conflict and procedural blocks. Now I'm using the following query,

```
WITH _a AS (
  UPDATE mytable1 SET name=expr1, last_name = expr2
  WHERE empId = expr3
  RETURNING empId 
), _b AS (
  INSERT INTO mytable1 (empId, name, last_name)
  SELECT(expr3, expr1, expr2)
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM _a)
  RETURNING empId
```

but unfortunately, if the query inserts data, it returns the key, and if it updates, it doesn't.

Is it possible to somehow rewrite the request so that it always returns the key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Comment: @Marc As far as I understand, the article is about `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE`. But my postgresql version does not allow using this query. I also can't use procedural blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow rewrite the request so that it always
> returns the key?

You are almost there.

Just use `union all` to combine results of `insert` and `update` statements.

```
WITH _a AS (
  UPDATE mytable1 SET name = expr1, last_name = expr2
  WHERE empId = expr3
  RETURNING empId 
), _b AS (
  INSERT INTO mytable1 (empId, name, last_name)
  SELECT expr3, expr1, expr2
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM _a)
  RETURNING empId 
)
SELECT empId FROM _a
UNION ALL
SELECT empId FROM _b;
```